# Rails Devise add role based on signup path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm building a `Rails 3` app, where I need to give users specific roles based on the path they take to sign up on the site. I am using Devise and Cancan.

So for instance, the path

`new-fundraiser` (or `/users/new/fundraiser`)

Needs to set `user.fundraiser = true` on user creation, and

`new-charity-user` (or `/users/new/charity`)

Needs to set `user.charity_owner = true` on user creation.

What is the easiest / best-practice way to accomplish this using Devise and Cancan?

Comment: do you consider alternative with two models? Fundraise and CharityOwner (and two routes, each for model), not the DRYest solution.

Comment: why not use single sign up, with either a select box to select the "role" they want for sign-up. maybe even leave the role outside the signup process, and let the user to set the role as soon as he first logs in. signup processes should be super simple

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not an option, as we have two different kinds of users that should be treated completely different, and the checkbox solution isnt polished enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would set up a route like:

```
match "/users/new/:role", :to => 'users#new'
```

In your user model I'd add an accessor:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def role=(role_name)
    @role = role_name
    case role_name
    when 'charity'
      self.charity_owner = true
    when 'fundraiser'
      self.fundraiser = true
    else
      # raise some exception
    end
  end

  def role
    @role
  end
end
```

Then in your users#new.html.erb form add a hidden field:

```
<%= form.hidden_field :role, :value => params[:role] %>
```

Then your won't need to change your controller code at all.

Answer (score 9):

The original question suggests that @Houen had already customized Devise somewhat.  Here's a slightly tweaked answer that works with an out-of-the-box Devise set-up and many-to-many user-roles CanCan set-up.

First, in your routes, add:

```
devise_scope :user do
    match "/users/sign_up/:initial_role" => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => 'new_user_with_role'
end
```

You can then refer to this route like:

```
<%= link_to 'here', new_user_with_role_path(:initial_role => 'human') %>
```

Then, in your User model add

```
attr_accessible :initial_role

def initial_role=(role_name)
    @initial_role = role_name
    role = Role.find_by_name(role_name)
    self.roles << role
end

def initial_role
    @initial_role
end
```

And finally in views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb add

```
<%= f.hidden_field :initial_role, :value => params[:initial_role] %>
```

Comment: Hi Cailinanne - I really like our answer! Very clean - how would you tweak this best to work with the roles added on the Devise side as user.admin?, user.editor?, like in the Option 2 on the Devise wike here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role

Comment: @Houen I would recommend using Rolify to do that

Comment: @AZ.Completely agree. This old question has new and improved tools at the ready. To anybody coming here now, AZ is talking about https://github.com/EppO/rolify

Comment: I really liked this answer. So for anyone coming here after Rails 4.x, you should care about permitting the additional parameter in the sign_up form. Please refer to this answer for more details [Unpermitted Parameters adding new fields to Devise in rails 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19036427/119958)

Answer (score 1):

Using out-of-the-box Devise and CanCan, I set up my user "roles" according to Rails Casts #189 "Embedded Association."  However, I was unable to get @cailinanne's answer to work with my set up, as a different Roles approach was assumed.  If anyone has a similar problem, here is a much less elegant/robust approach that borrows from @cailinanne's answer.  It has the one advantage of not needing to modify the User model.

Use the "devise_scope" route and "link_to" code that @cailinanne provided.  Skip the changes to the User model.  Finally use the following code in views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
  <% if params[:initial_role] == "admin" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", :admin %>
  <% elsif params[:initial_role] == "moderator" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", :moderator %>
  <% elsif params[:initial_role] == "author" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[roles][]", :author %>
  <% end %>
```

This code replaces the check_box_tag code provided in the Rails Cast code.

This definitely needs more work.  I'll move the if-elsif-elsif logic into controller at some point, and reference it against User.ROLES so that it doesn't break if I add/remove a role. But, this  will get help you get the initial role assignment working if you took the Rails Casts "roles" approach.