# Virtual attributes with Devise in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, virtual-attribute

My User model doesn't have a `:name` field but I want to include a `:name` field in my sign up form which will be used to create a record of another model in an `after_create`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_thing

private
  def create_thing
    @thing = Thing.new
    @thing.name = <here's where I need help>
    @thing.save!
  end
end
```

How can I get the name from the sign up form?

Comment: My title is probably wrong so feel free to suggest a better one.

Comment: I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17384426/519632

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model add attr_accessor for name

```
attr_accessor :name
```

This will allow you to add it to a form and use it to generate the proper data in your after_create

Comment: What should go into `@thing.name = `?

Comment: `self.name` will pull from anything the controller passes back to the model

Answer (score 2):

Just as @trh said you can use a attr_accessor, but if you need to have it do some logic your gonna need to make getter and/or setter methods to accompany the attr_accessor.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
  after_create :create_thing

  def name
    #if need be do something to get the name 
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end

  def name=(value)
    #if need be do something to set the name 
    names = value.split
    @first_name = names[0]
    @last_name = names[1]
  end

  private
  def create_thing
    @thing = Thing.new
    @thing.name = self.name
    @thing.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: if your rails 4 your gonna need to add the params to strong params else if your using rails 3 you need an attr_accessible.